# How to change the font or size of jquery.ui selectmenu?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a trouble with jQueryUI selectmenu. I want to change font size or selectmenu size and I want to see label at the right of selectmenu. Here is my code:

```
<label for="names">Name:</label>
<select id="names">
    <option selected="selected">Choose name</option>
    <option>Bob</option>
    <option>Kate</option>
    <option>Rob</option>
</select>
```

If I put the selectmenu in the div I see a label under selectmenu. It is bad for me.

Thanks for replies!

Comment: did you try add css here - select#names option { font-size:18px; } ?

Comment: Put **select_menu** inside one div and lable inside other then use `float: left` css property to get the label at right of **select_menu**

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can simply change jquery selectmenu option item's style:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select#num_years").selectmenu({
      width: 200
    })
    .selectmenu("menuWidget")
    .addClass("option_class");

  $("select#num_years").selectmenu("widget").addClass("option_class");

});
```

```css
.option_class {
  font-size: 25px !important;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <select id="num_years" name="num_years">
    <option value="0" style="font-size: 14px !important;">All</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out this website:
http://www.fbloggs.com/2009/03/03/how-to-scale-the-jquery-ui-font-size-for-just-the-ui-widgets/

It shows how to scale all jquery ui widgets.

Comment: Thank you, taylor.